# Counting queries for 2d range trees using fractional cascading

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, range-tree

Are there any libraries that provided 2d range trees with fractional cascading, that have `O(log n)` complexity for range counting queries (i.e., `O(log^(d-1) n)` for d dimensions)?

One promising coded snippet I found is https://github.com/elazarl/RangeTree/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/elazarl/rangetree/RangeTree.java - however I can't work out how to modify this code so that I'm only counting, not reporting, the range count.

I know I can do this by adding a count to each leaf, then summing the leaves as I traverse. But I can't figure it out with fractional cascading!

Comment: did you find a suitable library?

Comment: @Andrew I gave up on this ideal for BHVs instead. Not ideal for the number of points I wanted to do, but culling the plot to the camera frustum helped a lot.